# Is it Cu²⁺ or Cu⁺²?

Tags: ions, notation

Is $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ or $\ce{Cu^{+2}}$ correct? In my book the author uses both but at different places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [standard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion#Notation) for ions is <sup>2+</sup>, not <sup>+2</sup>.

> The net charge is written with the magnitude *before* the sign; that is, a doubly charged cation is indicated as **2+** instead of **+2**.